# Why does network drive periodically become unavailable?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

I have two desktops on my home LAN. They both render images and deposit those image to a shared location. This had been a cloud service for a while, but I recently just shared the folder on my LAN so that one machine can write an image to that folder as a mapped network drive.

Periodically, the render fails on the "remote" machine because it cannot write the recently produced image to the mapped drive. Windows tells me something like "Could not find file with name..." for the given directory and says "The drive will not be reconnected." Every time I've seen this, Explorer has been able to browse the network location without any problems, but the render stopped because it couldn't write the file. The "server" had been up the whole time, and neither machine is allowed to sleep.

Any idea what's going on here? Is this a known limitation of network shares, that I need to solve with an additional tool/service? E.g. I can imagine a scenario where a software wants to write a file, and the network location is available, but isn't quite fast enough and the software isn't robust enough to handle that kind of delay; this would be a situation where I need some kind of middle-ware to mediate the write... but that's just a wild theory.

Could it be related to the known issue in this KB article from Windows 10 1809: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-network-drive-fail-reconnect Oct 2018 seems like a long time ago for this issue to still exist, but issues have hung around for longer, so it's not out of the question.

Any suggestions appreciated (I'll try to capture the exact error message next time it happens).

Comment: Have you checked Windows event log on client and server side for entries at the time when the access failed?

Comment: Try setting Persistence:  Net Use mapping command;  ...  /persistent:yes

Comment: Well... it hasn't come up again. I was hoping to post more information the next time it failed. I didn't see anything illuminating in the Event Log. Checking the log and setting persistent:yes are good suggestions.